# ListView rightclick selects item, left-click does not

Tags: windows-8

Im writing a windows 8 note-taking app and Ive got a Listview hooked up to a SQL database from Azure and a ListViewItem Template with a stackpanel and inside a checkbox plus some text..

When i left click or tap an item, it does not get selected, but rightclicking does.
How can i get it to select the listview item by leftclicking?

```
<ListView x:Name="noteListView" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="noteListView_ItemClick" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. You have to set `IsItemClickEnabled` to `False`
2. You have to handle the `SelectionChanged` event and not the click event

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="noteListView" Margin="20,0,0,0" 
IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="noteListView_SelectionChanged">
```

Comment: Yes but when I do it as you say, it does not select any items (except the first one, dont know why) so the SelectionChanged event does not fire

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski - Hmm... It is hard to know what is going on without more detail. It works fine for me. If I add the `Tapped` event for the `ListView`, that works too.

Comment: Turns out using the MobileServiceCollectionView from Azure is the cause of this... Must be a bug :(